# Applying AllowHtmlAttribute based on another property's value in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Consider the following:

```
public enum HtmlFieldType {
    PlainText,
    RichText,
    Number,
    DateTime,
    Radio,
    Checkbox,
    Unknown
}

public class MySimpleModel {
    public HtmlFieldType FieldType { get; set; }
    public bool IsMandatory { get; set; }
    public string[] Values { get; set; }
}
```

I'm wanting to set attributes on the `public string[] Values` property based on the value of `FieldType` dynamically. Things like DataType, IsRequired, and AllowHtml. Specifically, if FieldType is set to RichText, then Values should use the AllowHtmlAttribute.

I've explored using a validator provider, as well as an associated metadata provider. In both cases it doesn't appear obvious as to how to interrogate another property of the model. Am I on the right path? This has stumped me for a few hours, so any help would be tremendously appreciated!

EDIT: I've also attempted implementing IValidatableObject, but it's my understanding that MVC handles property validation before firing the Validate function. If my Values property contains HTML it'll stop execution before hitting Validate.